# How to use ListView in DataGrid's field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datagrid

I have a list of files (stored in db which I get using Linq), I want to put them in ASP ListView (or something better for this case if you can suggest).

This files are attachments to policies, so one policy may have them more than one.

ListView will be placed in DataGrid's field, but I couldn't find a way to put it there and this is my question. I also want to be able to download these files, but I don't have elements that I could check if they were selected.

Additional info:
I bind data with DataGrid by

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = linqQuery.ToList();
myDataGrid.DataKeyField = "IdPolicy";
myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

In aspx I have Panel -> DataGrid -> Columns -> BoundColumns (with DataFields).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each item of DataGrid and populate ListView.

[image]

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    OnItemDataBound="DataGrid1_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IdPolicy" HeaderText="Policy" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Files">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="Panel1">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" />
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItem %><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Policy
    {
        public int IdPolicy { get; set; }
        public List<string> Files { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Policy> _policies;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            _policies = new List<Policy>();
            _policies.Add(new Policy
            {
                IdPolicy = 1,
                Files = new List<string> {"One.jpg", "Two.jpg"}
            });

            _policies.Add(new Policy
            {
                IdPolicy = 2,
                Files = new List<string> {"TwentyOne.jpg", "TwentyTwo.jpg"}
            });

            DataGrid1.DataSource = _policies;
            DataGrid1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DataGrid1_DataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var policy = e.Item.DataItem as Policy;

            var listView1 = e.Item.FindControl("ListView1") as ListView;

            listView1.DataSource = policy.Files;
            listView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful ;). Very comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridTemplateColumn, and add the ListView to the ItemTemplate. The ListView will be nested in the DataGrid, so you will need to bind it programatically in the ItemDataBound event (or elsewhere).

```
((ListView)e.Item.FindControl("ListView1")).DataSource = ListViewDataSource;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was also helpful.